# Detection of Redundant Constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, linear-programming

Suppose I pose the following query to a constraint logic programming
system:

?- Y <= 6 - X, Y <= (- 4) + 4 * X, Y <= 4 + X / 3.

Are there systems that would recognize the last inequality as
redundant and remove?

The problem is especially annoying since in contrast to equality
equations there is no upper bound on the number of independent
constraints. But nevertheless it might happen in linear inequalities
that one constraint is made redundant by others.

Any fast way to detect the situation?

Bye

Comment: Dedection should either be Detection or Deduction.  I'd guess Detection, but Deduction is also edit distance 1 from Dedection.  

Comment: given the question in the last sentence, i edited the title. i also added the tag 'linear-programming'---I hope you are ok with it.

Comment: Thank you for detecting the mistake and then deducing a correction.

Answer (score 10):

This can be done via linear programming.  Consider a set of linear inequalities $Ax \leq b$, together with an additional inequality $c^Tx \leq d$.  We wish to know if the constraint $c^Tx \leq d$ is redundant.

Consider the linear program:

$\max c^Tx$ subject to

$Ax \leq b$,

$c^T x \leq d+1$.

The constraint $c^Tx \leq d$ is implied by $Ax \leq b$ if the above linear program has optimal value at most $d$.

In the degenerate case that the above LP is infeasible, then $c^Tx \leq d$ is redundant if and only if $Ax \leq b$ is infeasible.

Comment: I like the reformulation of redundancy as an implication. Do you think this is a "fast way" to do it? 

Comment: Linear programming is "fast" (in practice) so I'd say yes.  Also, by testing each constraint for redundancy one at a time, we can get down to a "minimal" system.  If what you really care about is getting down to a minimal system, I'd guess there is a slicker way.  But if you want to test if a *particular* constraint is redundant, I can't think of anything that would be much faster.

Comment: I want that t-shirt!

Comment: I am coming from the future.  If you see this, can you tell me why do we need $c^\top x \leq d+1$ ??
@Tony Huynh

Comment: The $c^T x \le d+1$ constraint is not needed.

Comment: @independentvariable It is only there to rule out the possibility that the LP is unbounded.

Comment: @TonyHuynh thanks :)