# Better tactics for removing redundant constraints than Linear Programming?

Tags: convex-polytopes, linear-programming, convex-optimization

After reading:

[Detection of Redundant Constraints](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/69662/detection-of-redundant-constraints)

It appears that linear-programming is the most commonly known way to remove ALL redundant constraints from a system of inequalities of the form

$$ Ax \le b$$

Short of some heuristic techniques.

I found this hard to believe, so I kept digging around and found:

https://www.emis.de/journals/HOA/MPE/Volume2010/723402.pdf

But what surprises me is that the techniques listed do NOT find ALL the redundant constraints, except linear programming itself.

So that gets me curious, do we not have any faster techniques of detecting ALL redundant constraints than linear programming?

I don't see this written anywhere explicitly, so I want to believe there exist quicker techniques, but i'm having difficulty finding anything on the internet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know why you find this surprising.  Saying that a particular linear inequality $a x \le b$ is non-redundant is exactly the statement that the linear programming problem, maximize $a x$ subject to the other constraints, does not have an optimal solution with objective value $\le b$.  Linear programming is the natural way to check this, especially given the availability of high-quality linear programming software.

Comment: As per first comment's pdf - in the pdf it is stated that heuristic method found more redundant constraints than LP method. Are those redundancies valid? Is LP the only method that guarantees that we will find all redundancies? Thanks.

Comment: @BojanVukasovic That would be a good question to ask the authors of the pdf.  In principle, linear programming should find all redundant constraints, but roundoff errors could potentially mess things up.

Answer (score 4):

Forgive me for reviving this post, but I felt I should point out that it is a theorem that the complexity of LP and the complexity of removing all redundant constraints is the same.

[1997. Telgen, Jan. On Redundancy In Systems Of Linear Inequalities](https://ageconsearch.umn.edu/record/272154)

Answer (score 1):

A 2016 paper of Emeritus Professor H.P. Williams may be of interest . It  follows a 1986 American Mathematical Monthly paper by the same author. It is based on  Fourier - Motzkin  Elimination. The reference is:

"The dependency diagram of a linear programme", Journal of the Operational Research Society (2016) **67**, 450-456.